Flutter riverpod: Non visible page refreshes because of ref.watch()
I am building an app, where I have the following scenario:
Homepage -> Chatpage -> Profilepage
The "->" indicates routing in form of push for example like this:
navigatorKey.currentState?.push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => ScreenPartyInfo(partyId: partyId),
  ),
);

On my Homepage I am watching a provider:
final partyListData = ref.watch(partyListStateProvider);
If routed to my Profilepage and modify that provider the Homepage, which is not visible at this point, gets updated. How can I prevent this behaviour?
I want it to refresh on changes if it is open and visible. Routing also must be like this, because i need the go back function.
The partyListStateProvider is a normal StateNotifierProvider.

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Riverpod updates your page because it is "alive". when you change to a page you use push() method, if you used replace() your Home page would be destroyed and the corresponding provider would disposed too.
If I can understand you, the replace() method is not the best solution for your project right now, thus you had to see your page updated even if not visible.
